# URL rewriting whilst using codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, codeigniter, url-rewriting

I am using the following to remove my index.php in codeigniter -

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I am replacing an old site with my new one written with codeigniter, because of this I need to rewrite some old urls to new ones. This is working fine for single pages, however I am running into a problem with the following rewrite -

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/comments/(.*)/$ /location/$1
```

This should in theory redirect you from:
http://www.mysite.com/comments/123 to http://www.mysite.com/location/123

Because I’m removing index.php through a rewrite I am ending up being directed to -

http://www.mysite.com/location/123?/comments/123/

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not mix mod_alias (`RedirectMatch`) and mod_rewrite. Try this mod_rewrite rule instead:

```
RewriteRule ^comments/(.*)/$ /location/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Now just make sure to put this rule in front of your other rule.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not that great at URL re-writing. Thought I shouldn't mix the two but was the only way I could find to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Finally got it, for those that are interested, I had to add comments to a rewrite condition that I failed to mention in the first post:

`RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|media|images|css|js|comments|robots\.txt)`

Hopefully this may help somebody else.